# Batching channel output in Go

Tags: go, channel

I have a routine that consumes elements of a channel. The elements are available at arbitrary times (the channel is connected to a network socket where different clients provide input at different times) and need to be pushed through a rate-limited API that can take batches of elements at once.

My current solution is to use a list container and a ticker: a goroutine grabs elements out of the channel and pushes them to a list, then a ticker that fires every "minimum amount of time to not get throttled" grabs the content of the list and pushes it to the rate-limited API.

I came up with this (I apologize, I'm so not a Go programmer):

```golang
// simulate the channel
c := make(chan int, 100)
go func() {
    for i := 1; i < 30000; i++ {
        c <- i
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}()

// block-read the channel
l := []int{}
var m sync.Mutex
go func(list *[]int) {
    for val := range c {
        m.Lock()
        *list = append(*list, val)
        m.Unlock()
    }
}(l)

// read batches every tick
for range time.Tick(1 * time.Second) {
    buf := append([]int{}, l...)
    m.Lock()
    l = l[len(buf):]
    m.Unlock()
    sendBuffer(buf)
}
```

Is this OK?

I was also thinking of using `select` non-blocking poll to "read all available messages" and then send and sleep, but the above way seemed more go-ish, maybe?

Also, what obvious pitfalls am I missing due to my non-understanding of Go?

Comment: `list` is not concurrent safe so your code has data race at `l.PushBack(val)` and `buf.PushBackList(l)` both of these statements are not synchronized, Also as you said you can use `select` to track both `timer` and process batch data

Comment: also any specific reason to use `list` and not `slice`?

Comment: @GauravDhiman, because I was afraid. I tested some code, and hence I edited my code to use a slice pointer instead of a list. I also added syncing, just to make sure. LMKYT?

Comment: assuming you meant `}(l)` instead of `}(list)`, there is still a data race at `buf := append([]int{}, l...)` as its not inside the lock.

Comment: fixed the syntax error. @GauravDhiman, What's wrong with reading the slice outside of the lock? worst case I won't get as many values as I would have liked, but I'm not losing anything - right?

Comment: `*list = append(*list, val)` modifies `list` and `buf := append([]int{}, l...)` access the list `without synchronization` hence `data race`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
c := make(chan int, 100)
go func() {
    for i := 1; i < 30000; i++ {
        c <- i
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}()

ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
defer ticker.Stop() // release resources

data := make([]int, 0)

for {
    select {
        case <- ticker.C:
            sendBuffer(data)
            data = make([]int, 0)
        case i := <- c:
            data = append(data, i)
    }
}
```

using `select` here prevents data race as only one of the case will execute, also if you want you can make `sendBuffer` non-blocking